# Why Order of Vertices Change Rendering Behaviour

Tags: directx, directx-11

I am following a beginner level DirectX tutorial. I have realized that the order I put vertices in vertex buffer, makes or breaks the rendering. For example, this draws a triangle

```
myVertex vertices[] = {
    XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.4f, 0.5f),
    XMFLOAT3(0.4f, -0.4f, 0.5f),
    XMFLOAT3(-0.4f, -0.4f, 0.5f),
};
```

while this draws nothing,

```
myVertex vertices[] = {
    XMFLOAT3(-0.4f, -0.4f, 0.5f),
    XMFLOAT3(0.4f, -0.4f, 0.5f),
    XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.4f, 0.5f)
};
```

- Does it supposed to work in both cases?
- If not, how can I determine the correct ordering of vertices for Directx to draw?

Comment: Search for: Backface Culling. This is enabled by default in directx 11 I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the rasterizer settings, which allows to cull triangles depending if they appear to be clockwise ordered or counter clockwise ordered when they are in screen space.

By default [D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ns-d3d11-d3d11_rasterizer_desc) has the property: 
D3D11_CULL_MODE which has the 3 options :
* D3D11_CULL_NONE
* D3D11_CULL_FRONT
* D3D11_CULL_BACK

To determine which triangles are front or back facing, you use the property :
FrontCounterClockwise

If false, triangle is back facing in case they are counter clockwise, and front facing is clockwise.

If true, it will be the opposite.

The default rasterizer settings (if you do not create a state and assign it to the pipeline), is D3D11_CULL_BACK and FrontCounterClockwise=FALSE

So by default, clockwise triangles will not be displayed.

If you want to draw every triangle regardless, you can create a rasterizer state and use: 
D3D11_CULL_NONE

To create a rasterizer state , use [ID3D11Device::CreateRasterizerState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11device-createrasterizerstate)

To attach the resulting state to the pipeline, use [ID3D11DeviceContext::RSSetState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-rssetstate)